# Entity Framework not showing added column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-5

I have a question about Entity Framework. I am no expert on it and only started using it recently but I'm a little confused by it.

Basically I have updated a stored procedure to now returns an extra column of data. I can execute this stored procedure in SQL Server and pass it custom data and it returns showing the column.

However in Visual Studio when I update model from database I don't get the column. Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Things I've tried include:

1. Run context.tt custom tool
2. Rerun update model from database.
3. Check to make sure the stored procedure is running correctly.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework 5.0 for your fyi. I appreciate any help with this issue. Thanks again

Comment: I posted an answer but was wrong... check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356566/add-stored-procedure-to-entity-framework

Comment: Cool I'll try that..... I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Actually I'll try this but I'm not sure will it work cause my stored procedure is running it's just when I update it it's not being imported into the project.

Comment: Did you try to delete it out of EF and add it again? EF is a fickle beast.

Comment: Ya I tried that but it didn't work... I got it in the end by individually going into my context.tt file and specifically choosing the procedure I was trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

I got it in the end by individually going into my context.tt file and specifically choosing the procedure I was trying to update.